# Two XML sitemaps for one page rewrited in .htaccess

Tags: php, xml, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created two sitemap files for the same page:

- sitemap_en.xml
- sitemap_sk.xml

Same page is working on two domains.

- domain1 - for sk language
- domain2 - for en language

I need to create following rewrite rule in .htaccess:

- If domain1.sk/sitemap.xml Return sitemap_sk.xml
- If domain2.com/sitemap.xml Return sitemap_en.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following conditional rules in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

##1)if host=="www.domain1.sk##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.sk$
##rewrite "/sitemap.xml" to "/sitemap_sk.xml"##
RewriteRule ^/?sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap_sk.xml [NC,L]
##2)if host=="www.domain2.com##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$
##rewrite "/sitemap.xml" to "/sitemap_en.xml"##
RewriteRule ^/?sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap_en.xml [NC,L]
```

- The first rule will rewrite **/sitemap.xml** to **/sitemap_sk.xml** if the host value is **www.domain1.sk** or  **domain1.sk** .
- The #2 rule will rewrite **/sitemap.xml** to **/sitemap_en.xml** if the host value is **www.domain.com** or **domain.com** .

Comment: ...and is it possible to disable direct access to original sitemap? domain.com/sitemap_en.xml ??

Comment: @Steelbull yes it is possible, you can use this rule above other rules ,add this bellow the "RewriteEngine on" line `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sitemap_en\.xml [NC]

RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]` this will return 403 forbidden error if **/sitemap_en.xml** is direct accessed